# Writing multiple lines of user input text to a file and ending writing session with user defined command in C

Tags: c, linux

I need to write multiple lines of user defined text to into a file in linux.

I have this code above but my writing session ends when I push return(enter) but I dont want it to end with an enter when I press enter I want my program to go to next line so I would be able to write multiple lines of text into that file.

At end I want my program to stop writing session when I push CNTL+D any ideas about this please ?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main() 
{ 
    char c[1000]; 
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr=fopen("program.txt","w");
    printf("Enter a sentence:\n"); 
    gets(c); 
    fprintf(fptr,"%s",c); 
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Need a loop that filters out `'\n'`.

Comment: Use a while loop.  Don't use `gets`.  `Use fgets`

Comment: Note that `gets()` (which should not be used in the first place) removes the newline, but your `fprintf()` does not add it back again.

Comment: What is the meaning of filterin '\n' also how should I define while loop I guess I need to define like this...while(when ctnl+D) pressed) this is idea of course how will ı write the code ?
Also fgets not recognised by the complier.

Comment: You might like to take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20149183/694576 to a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

@Bugra Sezer, `fgets` should be in stdio.h.  You want some variation on this, which will end on either a blank line or ctrl-d.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    char c[1000];
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr=fopen("program.txt","w");

    printf("Enter a sentence:\n");

    while (fgets(c, 1000, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(c, "\n") == 0)
            break;

        fprintf(fptr,"%s",c);
        printf("Enter a sentence:\n");
    }

    fclose(fptr);

    return(0);
}
```